# setPropertyActionListener is not setting the target value in the bean

Tags: spring, jsf, primefaces

I am trying to set some information in dialogue box when the search button is clicked but the problem I am facing is that **f:setPropertyActionListener** is not setting the target value in the backing bean so when the popup comes its empty.

Dialogue box looks like this :

```
<h:form id="form">
        <p:fieldset legend="Saved Branches" style="margin-bottom: 30px;">
            <p:dataTable id="branches" var="branch" value="#{branchOnBoarding.savedBranches}">
                <f:facet name="header">
        Branch Information
    </f:facet>
                <p:column headerText="Branch Name">
                    <h:outputText value="#{branch.branchName}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Branch Code">
                    <h:outputText value="#{branch.branchCode}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Building">
                    <h:outputText value="#{branch.building}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Street">
                    <h:outputText value="#{branch.street}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="City">
                    <h:outputText value="#{branch.city}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="State">
                    <h:outputText value="#{branch.state}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Country">
                    <h:outputText value="#{branch.country}" />
                </p:column>
             <p:column style="width:32px;text-align: center">
         <p:commandButton update=":form:branchDetail" oncomplete="PF('branchDialog').show()" icon="ui-icon-search" title="View">
            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{branch}" target="#{branchOnBoarding.selectedBranch}" />
        </p:commandButton>
    </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
                <p:dialog header="Branch Info" widgetVar="branchDialog">
    <p:outputPanel id="branchDetail" style="text-align:center;">
        <p:panelGrid  columns="2" rendered="#{not empty branchOnBoarding.selectedBranch.branchName}" columnClasses="label,value">

            <h:outputText value="Branch Name:" />
            <h:outputText value="#{branchOnBoarding.selectedBranch.branchName}" />

            <h:outputText value="Branch Code:" />
            <h:outputText value="#{branchOnBoarding.selectedBranch.branchCode}" />

            <h:outputText value="Building:" />
            <h:outputText value="#{branchOnBoarding.selectedBranch.building}" />

            <h:outputText value="Street:" />
            <h:outputText value="#{branchOnBoarding.selectedBranch.street}" />

            <h:outputText value="City:" />
            <h:outputText value="#{branchOnBoarding.selectedBranch.city}" />

            <h:outputText value="State:" />
            <h:outputText value="#{branchOnBoarding.selectedBranch.state}" />

            <h:outputText value="Country:" />
            <h:outputText value="#{branchOnBoarding.selectedBranch.country}" />
        </p:panelGrid>
    </p:outputPanel>
</p:dialog>
        </p:fieldset>
```

Code for backing bean looks like this :

```
@Component(value="branchOnBoarding")
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
@SpringScopeView
public class BranchOnBoarding implements Serializable{

    private BranchUI branchUI = new BranchUI();
    private List<Branch> savedBranches = new ArrayList<>();
    private Branch selectedBranch;



public Branch getSelectedBranch() {
    return selectedBranch;
}

public void setSelectedBranch(Branch selectedBranch) {
    this.selectedBranch = selectedBranch;
}

public List<Branch> getSavedBranches() {
    savedBranches = branchDao.findAll();
    //for(Branch b:savedBranches)
        //System.err.println(b.getBranchName());
    return savedBranches;
}

public void setSavedBranches(List<Branch> savedBranches) {
    this.savedBranches = savedBranches;
}

}
```

Dialogue box looks like this :

[image]

Comment: Don't mix Spring and non-spring annotations (instead of tagging it primefaces or java you should have tagged it spring... )

Comment: Use the action of the command button instead of a f:setPropertyActionListener and create a method in your bean to set it something like: setSelectedBranch(Branch branch); If I'm not mistaken the action from the listener is running after the update of the commandbutton. In order to check that just add a command button on the popup with an update to it.